# Angular: create one Observable list from other and retrieve it

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'd like to create a function returning an observable with a list that I created with several observable. I think I'm very close from the solution as the debugger stop just one step before displaying the list.
Here is my code:
ts

```
this.carService.getEveryCar().subscribe((response) => {
    this.cars = response; 
});
```

service:

```
getEveryCar(): Observable<any> {
    let cars = [];
    this.getCars()
      .subscribe(response => {
        cars = response.list;
        this.getOneMoreCar.subscribe(
          response =>{
              cars = response.list;
              return of(cars)
        })
      }
   return of(cars);
}
```

When I debug I get cars declared as empty till the end when the cars array is filled but then my ts file stop calling the service.

What can I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: See the aforementioned suggested duplicate. Asynchronous calls are a common and critical building block in writing/designing an application. It is critical that you understand how to work with asynchronous calls in javascript, and by extension typescript. Understanding these core concepts will help you become a better programmer and also ensure you do not keep "stubbing your toe" on the same problem.

Comment: What's `getCars` and `getOneMoreCar`?

Comment: And as a side note If you want to use the response from one observable in a call to another you can also use `switchMap`

Comment: You have assigned cars variable twice. One with getCars() response and other with getOneMoreCar() response. Which one you actually want to fill your cars variable with?

Answer (score 0):

You should not make any subscription in the service. This is the best way to chain observables.

```
import { of, concatMap } from "rxjs/operators";
...
getEveryCar(): Observable<any> {
    let cars = [];
    return this.getCars()
      .pipe(concatMap(response => {
          cars = response.list;
          return this.getOneMoreCar()
                     .pipe(concatMap(response => of([cars, response.list])));
      }));
}
```